# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with multiple ViewType ==> Blank screen?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with multiple ViewType in my current project it shows black screen!!?

can anyone help me to resolve this??

does the problem in code or layout ?? or some thing else

> The problem with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter what we found is the way it
>   is written can never support multiple view types. is it true ?

**my java code:**

```
private void displayChatMessages() {

    RecyclerView listOfMessages = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRv);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
            ChatMessage.class, R.layout.list_item_chat, RecyclerView.ViewHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final ChatMessage user,
                                          final int position) {
            switch (user.getMessageUser()) {
                case "test@test.com":
                    HolderMe vh1 = (HolderMe)viewHolder;
                    populateType1(vh1, user, position);
                    toaa1("cbn");
                    break;
                case "test2@test2.com":
                    populateType2((HolderYou) viewHolder, user, position);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    populateType3((HolderDate) viewHolder, user, position);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType) {
                case 1:
                    View userType1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout_holder_me, parent, false);
                    toaa1("cbn2");
                    return new HolderMe(userType1);
                case 2:
                    View userType2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout_holder_you, parent, false);
                    return new HolderYou(userType2);
                case 3:
                    View userType3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout_holder_date, parent, false);
                    return new HolderDate(userType3);
            }
            return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            ChatMessage user = getItem(position);
            switch (user.getMessageUser()) {
                case "test@test.com":
                    toaa1("cbn3");
                    return 1;
                case "test2@test2.com":
                    return 2;
                case "3":
                    return 3;
            }
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        private void populateType1(HolderMe v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            v.getTimeView().setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm",model.getMessageTime()));
            v.getTextv().setText(model.getMessageText());
        }

        private void toaa1( String text) {
            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        private void  populateType2(HolderYou vv, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            vv.getTextv().setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm",model.getMessageTime()));
            vv.getTimeView().setText(model.getMessageText());
        }
        private void populateType3(HolderDate vcv, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            vcv.getDate().setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm",model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
    listOfMessages.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**my xml:**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.marxhack.ma153.ActivityChatNew"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_activity_chat_new">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msginput"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.17"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRv"
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT : Problem solved**

```
    .
    .
    .
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRv);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with something like this yesterday, and I clearly remember the layout was a field variable, so it seems to me that it must be true then. Upon closer inspection I can see that is also final, so you can change it once is initiated.

[image]

Something to take in mind here is the Firebase-Ui libraries, any of them, are meant to speed up your starting project. After a while or while dealing with more complex cases, you will have to take care of it.

In this case, if you take a look at the library classes you will see that the bigger advantage is the switch case they use to handle the `child event listener` that is updating your data. Check that out, and maybe a pull request can help us all, good luck my friend :)